# Is there a countable order-dense family of open subsets of $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, order-theory

Consider $(0,1)$ with the usual topology, and let $\mathcal{V}$ be a family of open sets.
Say that $\mathcal{V}$ is *nested* iff $V \subseteq V'$ or $V' \subseteq V$ for any $V,V' \in \mathcal{V}$.
Call a family $\mathcal{U}$ of open sets *($\subseteq$-)order-dense in $\mathcal{V}$* iff for any $V \subsetneq V'$ in $\mathcal{V}$, there is some $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $V \subsetneq U \subsetneq V'$.

(Q) Is there, for any *nested* family $\mathcal{V}$ of open sets, a *countable* family $\mathcal{U}$ of open sets that is order-dense in $\mathcal{V}$?

Motivation: by e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538099), the answer to (Q) is 'yes' if and only if any nested family $\mathcal{V}$, equipped with the order $\subseteq$, is order-isomorphic to a subset of $[0,1]$ equipped with the usual order $\leq$.
(Hence homeomorphic when $\mathcal{V}$ is given the order topology.)

My progress: let $\mathcal{U}$ be the set of all countable unions of open intervals with rational endpoints. $\mathcal{U}$ is order-dense in $\mathcal{V}$, but it fails to be countable. I have tried and failed to reduce it to a countable set without losing order-denseness. 
As for constructing a counter-example, I have not had any good ideas. 
Nor have I found any useful answers on this board, nor elsewhere online.

Bonus (I conjecture the answer is 'no'): 
(Q$'$) Is there a countable family $\mathcal{U}$ of open sets that is order-dense in $\tau$, the family of *all* open sets?

Comment: It seems very unnatural to require strict containments in the density definition.

Comment: The set of all countable unions of open intervals with rational endpoints is $\tau$. It is certainly order-dense in $\mathcal V$, *assuming* the definition of order-dense is edited as follows: For any $V \subsetneq V'$ in $\mathcal V$, there is some $U\in\mathcal U$ such that $V \subseteq U\subseteq V'$.

Comment: thank you for accepting my answer, I assume you realize your question remains unanswered, and (I think) becomes more interesting, under a slightly different definition of "order-dense", as in my previous comment. Welcome to MSE! The following question and answer about uncountable linear are interesting, although not directly related to yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666481 Also, the following is related to uncountable orders, but again not quite related to your questions https://ims.nus.edu.sg/events/2019/recur/files/liuzhen.pdf You might edit your question (and unaccept my answer :)

Comment: @Mirko thanks! You answered the question I needed answering.
But as you say: a nearby interesting question is (Q), with order-denseness redefined as in your first comment.

Comment: @Mirko I don't understand your comment. "It is certainly order-dense in $\mathcal V$." I guess "It" is $\tau$, but what is $\mathcal V$?

Comment: @bof I meant $\tau$ is order-dense in *any* $\mathcal V\subseteq\tau$ (trivially), but provided we assume the modified definition of order-dense, with  $V \subseteq U \subseteq V'$ in place of $V \subsetneq U \subsetneq V'$. In fact, with this definition, any $\mathcal V$ is order-dense in itself.

Comment: @Mirko Oh. Somehow I was thinking that, when we say "$\mathcal U$ is order-dense in $\mathcal V$", it is assumed that $\mathcal U\subseteq\mathcal V$. I see now that the definition doesn't say that.

Comment: @bof I was trying to answer the modified version of the question (with $V \subseteq U \subseteq V'$), and got tired of trying, posted another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3306935 (it is also linked on the side). I wonder if we require that $\mathcal U\subseteq\mathcal V$ (when $\mathcal V$ is nested), would this change the problem much? Perhaps if one could find a countable $\mathcal U$ that works, not necessarily $\mathcal U\subseteq\mathcal V$, then one could use it to find another countable $\mathcal U'\subseteq\mathcal V$ that works...

Comment: @KevinCarlson I tried to think of the version of the question when we only require non-strict containments in the density definition. I only got entangled, posted a question (now linked) that I believed might be relevant, only to realize the answer to that was easy and I had thought of it earlier today but forgot it. So, anyway, I do find the version with non-strict inequalities interesting, and I do not know the answer to that (but I feel hesitant myself to post yet another similar question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take $\mathcal V=\{V,V'\}$ 
where $V'=(0,1)$ and $V=(0,\frac12)\cup(\frac12,1)$. 
Note that if there were $U$ with $V \subsetneq U \subsetneq V'$, then $V'$ would contain at least two points that $V$ does not, but $V'$ has only one extra point. Thus (if we require strict inclusions, as in the statement of the problem) there is no family $\mathcal U$ whatsoever that is order-dense in $\mathcal V$, simply because there is no $U$ that could be inserted strictly between $V$ and $V'$ for  the above choice of $\mathcal V$. (Similar reasoning for the bonus problem.)

Comment: Who said $\mathcal V$ is countable?

Comment: @KevinCarlson I "cheated" and deleted the part of my answer that assumed that $\mathcal V$ were countable. What is left is a complete and correct answer, although admittedly not that interesting: One might want to know what happens under some slightly different assumptions and requirements. (There is something along the lines that $\mathcal V$ could perhaps be reduced to a countable family, using that $(0,1)$ is hereditarily Lindel\"of, but the details are not clear to me.)